# Add image.png to top of image.jpg with ffmpeg became more dark

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to create frame for picture use FFMPEG so its logic same as watermark. so i used this code

```
ffmpeg -i output_1920x1280.jpg -vf "movie=cpf-border.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" -q:v 1 withBorder.jpg
```

and try with diff command like this

```
ffmpeg -i output_1920x1280.jpg -i cpf-border.png -pix_fmt rgba -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" withBorder.jpg
```

but still same. there no error but the result of image its more dark. cause the frame base on white color so i saw that when do side by side can you help me maybe there another syntax to handle this or use another tools

[image: This the border in .png format]
[image: This the base image]
[image: This the result its more dark than the original]

Comment: In case you saw my answer, I have updated it with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some kind of bug related to [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space conversion.

We may select `rgba` format for each input before the overlay, and select `rgb24` format after the overlay:

```
ffmpeg -y -i output_1920x1280.jpg -i cpf-border.png -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba[v1];[1]format=rgba[v2];[v1][v2]overlay=0:0,format=rgb24" -q:v 1 -src_range 0 -dst_range 1 withBorder.jpg
```

---

Result:
[image]